# How to authorize a compute engine to access a secured servlet in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, servlet-3.0, java-security

I deployed a jar file in a `compute engine`, this jar file trying to access a `servlet` deployed in `app-engine` with this details:

servlet path: `https:/pathToAppEngine/tasks/sendMail`

and its secured by this:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>my-tasks</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/tasks/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

And the compute engine is linked to a `service account` with `owner` privileges And both app-engine and compute engine instance are within the same google project

as a result, whenever this jar file (in compute engine) try to access this servlet (in app engine) it shows the google login page.

And if I removed the security from this servlet then it can be accessed easily from that jar file

so how can I authorize this compute engine to access this secured servlet in app-engine plz?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behaviour you are seeing right now is expected, as the [`<security-constraint>`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication) enforces authentication for [Google Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/users/#Java_Authentication_options) which requires a Google Account or G Suite Domain.

You might want to look at the [Endpoins Auth](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication) documentation instead of using `<security-constraint>` if you will be using a service account authenticating these requests.

Also, you could create you own logic in your App Engine code and add an [API key](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key) or your own auth string to your request.

```
GET https://application.com/endpoint&key=###
```

you could always obfuscate the key.

Lastly, you could also implement your own auth logic when sending the request from the compute engine instance to App Engine.c cheers